# At the submit button start time and end time to be calculate by javascript

Tags: javascript

i have tried to get start time and end time by java-script  but i dono how to get on submit button it have to run on side of submit button how much time to run a Report...

```
var begin_date = new Date();
//begin_time = begin.date.getTime();
begin_time = begin_date.getMilliseconds();
begin_date2 = begin_date;


var end_date = new Date();
//end_time = end_date.getTime();
end_time = end_date.getMilliseconds();
total_time = end_time - begin_time;


'Begin Time (ms): ' + begin_time;

'End time (ms): ' + end_time + "\n"+' Total time (ms): ' + total_time;
```

like wise i have to get in javascript ...how to achieve this ?

Comment: can u share ur complete code may be a fiddle link?
not ablt to understand what u really want to achieve?

Comment: Unless you are submitting your form via Ajax then you are not going to be able to get the time because the page will be refreshed an the begin_time will be lost.

Answer (score 1):

This script gives how much time Elapsed from start to end (till submit button pressed) - Time is in milliseconds.

SCRIPT:

```
var begin_date;
var btime1,btime2,btime3,btime;
var etime1,etime2,etime3,etime;
var end_date;
function f1(){
begin_date = new Date();
btime1=begin_date.getHours();
btime2=begin_date.getMinutes();
btime3=begin_date.getSeconds();
}
function f2(){
end_date = new Date();
etime1=end_date.getHours();
etime2=end_date.getMinutes();
etime3=end_date.getSeconds();
total_time = end_date-begin_date;
}
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#b1").click(function(){
  f2();  
  $("#start").val(btime1+":"+btime2+":"+btime3);
  $("#end").val(etime1+":"+etime2+":"+etime3);
});
});
```

HTML:

```
<body onload="f1()">
<button id="b1">button</button><br/><br/>
START: <input type="text" id="start">
END: <input type="text" id="end" >
</body>
```

Comment: but my question is while click on submit button it have to show start time: label endtime label on side of button ...

Answer (score 1):

Here's id the code that myt help ur purpose

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var datetime = new Date();
var starttime = datetime.getTime();
$('#abc').click(function () {
    var datetime1 = new Date();
    var endtime = datetime1.getTime();

    alert(starttime);
    alert(endtime);
    var time_diff = starttime - endtime;
    alert(time_diff);
});

});


<input type=button value=button id='abc'>
```

I have created created a demo fiddle for this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/u32pU/105/)

Comment: but my question is while click on submit button it have to show start time: label endtime label on side of button ...

Comment: I dont think that wud require much effort post your html code

Comment: and since your question has ""it have to run on side of submit button how much time to run a Report..."" it normally gives the user idea that u need time difference.

Try and remove any ambiguity from your post as much as u can